# PHP statements inside javascript external file

Tags: javascript, php

I need to do javascript action depends on $_SESSION php status:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] == true)
            {

echo <<<END

               $("#I-like-it").click(function()
               {

                 $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });


               });
               $("#I-dont-like-it").click(function()
               {

                  $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });


               });
END;

            }
            else
            {

               echo 'alert("You must be logged in to vote!")';


            }
```

This is external js file. How am I supposed to use PHP statements in this JS file?
My code doesnt work :c

Comment: You're not supposed to use PHP statements in a JavaScript file. The two languages execute in different places at different times. Either generate the correct HTML in PHP, or inject a JavaScript variable and have your JavaScript work from that.

Comment: Just use `.php` extension in your js file. Anyway, i would re-think the solution if i were you because something isn't OK there. There shouldn't be PHP code in a JS code.

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server, Javacript run on the browser.  You can pass information from PHP to Javascript, and you can pass information to the server FROM JavaScript.  But they cannot execute at the same time.

What I suggest doing is to use Javascript to read your PHP variable while it loads

```
<script>
 var serverSession = <? echo $_SESSION['logged'] ?>
</script>
```

Then your JavaScript can do whatever it needs to with that.

Comment: I tried to use like this: var serverSession = <? echo $_SESSION['logged'] ?> alert(serverSession); Its look like <? block code and alert doesnt open. Nothing working in this file if i put <? inside js file :c

Answer (score 0):

No, It can't, this is different type file, PHP is server side and JS is client side, but you can write javascript at your php file like this one :

```html
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] == true)
{
 echo '
 <script>
 $("#I-like-it").click(function(){
  $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });
 });
    $("#I-dont-like-it").click(function(){
     $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });
 });
 </script>
 ';
 
}
else
{
 echo '<script>alert("You must be logged in to vote!")</script>';
}
```

Comment: Well. In index.php file I put




<script src="admin_orders.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
And inside admin_orders.php your code. Nothing happens.

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] == true)
{
 echo '
 <script>
 $("#I-like-it").click(function(){
  $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });
 });
    $("#I-dont-like-it").click(function(){
     $(this).css({"font-size": "20px" });
 });
 </script>
 ';
 
}
else
{
 echo '<script>alert("You must be logged in to vote!")</script>';
}

Comment: This is cannot use script src, It is a php file, you can use "require function" like this at your index file require 'auth.php';